# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert'

Tags: javascript

Not able to find what is the wrong with the below code, let me know what is the issue...I am trying to construct the binary Search Tree and not able to construct.

```
function BinarySearchTree(){
  var Node = function(key){
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  };
  var root = null;
}
//Inserting a Key into a tree

this.insert = function(key){
  var newNode = new Node(key);
  if(root === null){
    root = newNode;
  }else{
    insertNode(root, newNode);
  }
};

var insertNode = function(node, newNode){
  if(newNode.key < node.key){
    if(node.left === null){
      node.left = newNode;
    }else{
      insertNode(node.left, newNode);
    }
  }else{
    if(node.right === null){
      node.right = newNode;
    }else{
      insertNode(node.right, newNode);
    }
  }
};


var tree = BinarySearchTree();
tree.insert(11);
```

Comment: I think instead of `this.insert =` you mean `BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert =`

Comment: I changed this.insert = to var insert = function(key) and BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(key) still showing the error...

Comment: Your `BinarySearchTree` doesn't return anything. Did you mean to use `new`?

Comment: Yes I want to construct New Binary Search Tree, the code given in the book is not working.. I was following the statements which are in the textbook. I tried to do var tree = new BinarySearchTree();  then message says tree.insert() is not a function.

Comment: You have some design problem that leads to scope problems. Define properly your objects and their constructor functions first. Which object type can do which actions? Then, refactor your code and move the functions at the proper place in the code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commenters mentioned a couple of problems with the code as it is that are causing hangups. First, you are using `this` outside of a `constructor` or `prototype` function, so `this` will be evaluated as referring to the global object. Also, when you assign `BinarySearchTree` to the variable `tree`, you are not calling a constructor function, so if you were to `console.log(tree)`, it would return the value `undefined`.

How then to fix your problem?

First, you can add a check within your `BinarySearchTree` (hereafter BST) definition to return an instance of the object, just in case you forget the `new` keyword.

```
if (!(this instanceof BinarySearchTree)) {
    return new BinarySearchTree();
}
```

Second, you want to bind your `Node` constructor and your `root` variable to the BST object  by replacing `var` with `this.Node` and `this.root`. Now you can access them later within the various `prototype` functions you will define.

Third, as mentioned, refactor your definition of the `insert` function as follows:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(){}
```

Of course, fill in the function with the appropriate code. Do the same for `insertNode`.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.insertNode = function(){}
```

I'm not saying the code will work, but this should create the prototypical inheritance you need for your tree to function as a object.

**Refactored**

```
function BinarySearchTree(){
  if (!(this instanceof BinarySearchTree)) {
    return new BinarySearchTree();
  }
  this.Node = function(key){
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  };
  this.root = null;
}
//Inserting a Key into a tree

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(key){
  var newNode = new this.Node(key);
  if(this.root === null){
    this.root = newNode;
  }else{
    this.insertNode(this.root, newNode);
  }
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insertNode = function(node, newNode){
  if(newNode.key < node.key){
    if(node.left === null){
      node.left = newNode;
    }else{
      this.insertNode(node.left, newNode);
    }
  }else{
    if(node.right === null){
      node.right = newNode;
    }else{
      this.insertNode(node.right, newNode);
    }
  }
};

var tree = BinarySearchTree();
tree.insert(11);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do couple of changes to make it work.

- use `prototype` to extend "constructor function" functionality
- use `new` to create instance of `BinarySearchTree`

```js
function BinarySearchTree(){
  this.Node = function(key){
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  };

  this.root = null;
}
//Inserting a Key into a tree

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(key){
  var newNode = new this.Node(key);
  if(this.root === null){
    this.root = newNode;
  }else{
    this.insertNode(this.root, newNode);
  }
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insertNode = function(node, newNode){
  if(newNode.key < node.key){
    if(node.left === null){
      node.left = newNode;
    }else{
      this.insertNode(node.left, newNode);
    }
  }else{
    if(node.right === null){
      node.right = newNode;
    }else{
      this.insertNode(node.right, newNode);
    }
  }
};


var tree = new BinarySearchTree();
tree.insert(11);
tree.insert(12);
tree.insert(10);

console.log(tree.root)
```